# Bringing the Wordpress Backend posts search to the frontend

Tags: wordpress, search

I work on a shop using WordPress and a discontinued (but still used) shopping plugin/theme.

The frontend search was never very good, even after some alterations to the way the search query is built. A fulltext index did help a bit, but it largely fails now, because there are many (almost) three-letter product names like t-700 / 700.

In the backend products search (must be a custom post type) however, the search is fine. It is just what the shop owner wants.

The perfect thing would be to bring just this backend search to the frontend, either by calling the right function / hook or by copying the relevant code.

The code structure pointed me to wp-includes/query.php, but there I failed to understand how backend queries work. I've been searching the web for days now and I just can't find anything at all.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you are using on frontend ?  you must use query_posts for all posts on frontend as it gives option to pass all possible arguments in it.

You can check this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for reference

Comment: Thank you! The frontend uses an ordinary SQL query with a mixture of MATCH AGAINST (for strings with strlen>3) and LIKE (for strlen == 2). shorter strings are being ignored.

Do you believe the frontend search should be made with query_posts instead?

Comment: SQL query is fine if its giving you the required result

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. The backend search is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

We need some more informations to help you! Without knowing the plugin you use or at least what's in the query.php it's impossible to help you.

The code for this search tool is specific so nobody can tell you how to get it to work in your frontend.

Usually I'd try to copy it into a frontend page (or try to call it there) but that might be a risk! Backend and frontend data should have different access rights, this might be the reason why you can't just copy&paste the function.

Comment: Thanks! The Code of the backend search is not very specific here...it is the default WordPress search api in wp-includes/query.php. I also tried copying before, but failed.